# How can compact fluoscent lamps light up?

Tags: visible-light

My understanding of fluorescent tubes is that filament on one side gets very hot, undergoes thermoionisation and shoots electrons into the gas. The collision between a mercury gas atom and a fast enough electron will eject a UV photon, later undergoing florescence to produce visible light.

However, I got confused when I looked at the compact fluorescent lamps installed in my ceiling (pictured below). They are helical, and I simply have no idea how the electrons decide that they want to go through the long spiral. It seems almost impossible that an electron could find its way though such a spiral to the other side (and I cannot see some external electric field either).

I would appreciate if someone could shed light (haha!) on how exactly the electrons make their way though the entire filament, to light up the entire globe.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but i'd guess that electrons find their way around the spiral in more or less the same way that electrons find their way along a not-straight length of copper wire.

Comment: P.S., The "fluorescence" tag might be misleading, since you are not asking anything about the mechanism by which the coating inside the tube converts the blue and ultraviolet emissions from the mercury ions into longer wavelengths of light.